# Is it possible to have a local group for an LDAP user

Tags: ldap

I have an LDAP server to which I do not have full privileges and an ubuntu system with LDAP authentication to which I am root. Is it possible to add an LDAP user to a local group?
(I don't know if I phrase this correctly but all I want is to have a user in LDAP in a group without editing the actual database)

Comment: LDAP is just a protocol for accessing data, what is the server software? You have said the data itself is persisted in a database so ultimately the only place it can be modified is in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your answer it seems like what you needed was:

`$ addgroup <group_name>` (to make the group)

`$ adduser -g <groupname> <username>` (to add the user to the group)

Answer (score 3):

OK silly me, just edited /etc/groups and worked

Comment: sorry this was a very long time ago and i had minimal understanding of how to configure unix users. My best recollection is that i added the ldap users to a group like i would a local user and it worked.